# .xib or storyboard file not found in existing app in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am totally fresher for ios development so please forgive me if my question is illogical.
I have one existing ios app and I want to modify only layout part but i didn't found any xib file or storyboard file

I had read something like that there are 3 files for every event-.xib,.h & .m
but In this application only .h and .m files are there..

My app folder is like :
SelectCountry(Folder)

SelectEvent.h

SelectEvent.m

My question is how do I change layout of particular page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UI doesn't necessarily has to be implemented from `xib` or `storyboard`. It can also be done programatically. This might be in your case. To make sure there's no `.xib` or `.storyboard` file in your project, press `Cmd+Shift+o` (<- letter O) and search for `.xib` or `.storyboard` in the popup.

If that yields no result, try searching for `initWithFrame` in your project.

Comment: I cannot find any xib or storyboard...What should I do?

Comment: Search for `initWithFrame`, `UILabel`, `UIButton` etc. in your code with `Cmd+Shift+F`.

Comment: yea, I searched that & I found it in every page..Thank you very much..It helps me

Comment: That means it was all done from code. Create a backup of that and start fiddling around till you get the hang of it.

Comment: yes, all GUI done from code..It is very difficult for me to change layout but I will try :)

Comment: how do I add click event of button buttonpressed:id(sender) in .h file without xid file..plz help me

Comment: That's a different question. Also, you probably should get a book and learn a bit more of Objective-C seeing you're lacking the foundation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70909/discussion-between-vidhi-trivedi-and-lord-zsolt).